# Confused about rewriting projection operator with orthonormal bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$. Let $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{X})$ be the column space of $\mathbf{X}$. Let $[\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{X})]^\perp$ be the orthogonal complement. Let $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{R}(X)}$ be a projection matrix such that $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{R}(X)}\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\hat{y}} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{X})$

Let $\mathbf{u}_{\mathbf{X}}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{X})$ and let $\mathbf{u}_{\mathbf{X}}$

$$\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{R}(X)} = \mathbf{u_X u_X^T}$$
$$\mathbf{P}_{[\mathcal{R}(X)]^\perp} = \mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp^T}$$

My teacher wrote on the board

$$\lVert \mathbf{P}_{[\mathcal{R}(X)]^\perp} \mathbf{y}\rVert_2^2 
= \lVert \mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp^T} \mathbf{y} \rVert_2^2 = \lVert \mathbf{u_\perp^T}\mathbf{y}\rVert_2^2 $$

Why would this be true? I don't see why $\mathbf{u}_\perp$ can vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\ \mathbf{p}\in{\cal R}(\mathbf{X})^\perp\ $, we have $\ \mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp}^\top\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{p}\ $, because the columns of $\ \mathbf{u_\perp}\ $ form an orthonormal basis of $\ {\cal R}(\mathbf{X})^\perp\ $.  In particular, $\ \mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp}^\top\mathbf{u_\perp}=\mathbf{u_\perp}\ $.  Also, for any $\ \mathbf{z}\in \mathbb{R}^n\ $, $\ \lVert \mathbf{z}\rVert_2^2=\mathbf{z}^\top\mathbf{z}\ $.  Using these identities, we get

\begin{align}
\lVert \mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp}^\top \mathbf{y} \rVert_2^2&=\mathbf{y}^\top\mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp}^\top\mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp}^\top \mathbf{y}\\
&=\mathbf{y}^\top\mathbf{u_\perp u_\perp}^\top \mathbf{y}\\
&= \lVert\mathbf{u_\perp}^\top \mathbf{y}\rVert_2^2\ .
\end{align}